# Adding a char at the end of every line in while loop

Tags: c

Can someone please help me with this problem, I want my program to print `+` with every end of line.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char str[65];
char * pch;
char str1[65];

fgets (str, 100, stdin); 

  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
   str1=pch;
    printf("=");
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

return 0;
}
```

With input, "Muhannad Stack" (output wrong):

```
=Muhannad
=Stack
```

Correct:

```
=Muhannad+
=Stack+
```

Therefore, my problem is how to add `+` at the end of every printed line

Comment: `str1=pch;
    printf("=");
    printf ("%s\n",pch);pch = strtok (NULL, " ");` --> `printf ("=%s=\n",pch);pch = strtok (NULL, " \n");` ?

Comment: You ask about `+` and show `=` — who's confused: you or me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
int main()
{    
  char str[65];
  char * pch;
  char str1[65];      
  fgets (str, 100, stdin);       
  pch = strtok (str,"\n");
  pch = strtok (pch," ");
  while (pch != NULL) {
    printf ("=%s+\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you retained `str1` in your example? Just curious. You could also write `for (pch=strtok(str, " "); pch; pch=strtok(NULL, " \n")) printf ("=%s+\n",pch);` Either way works.

Comment: Oh yes right, `str1` is of no use. ... and I had to add `pch = strtok (pch," ");` for it to work